# Does participating in an Area 51 site mean I personally support the proposal?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I want to ask a question about atheism. There is currently [an Atheism proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67058/atheism), and it appears that [[atheism]](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atheism) questions currently live on the Philosophy site.  I'm torn whether I should ask the more specific, proposed Q&A site, or the existing less specific site.

My thoughts are:

- Whether I personally support the creation of the site or not, the fact that I'm asking a question about its topic is a testament to the fact that it should have its own space--or at least be a part of the metrics used to determine if the proposal gets promoted or not.
- I'm not a part of the atheist or atheism-curious community enough to care if it has a site or not. Therefore, I should post to the existing site.

**Should I only participate in an Area 51 site if I *personally* support its advancement to production?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asking a question on Area 51 doesn't really mean anything about *you*.  You're just contributing a question, which you might be doing because you want the site to advance or might just be doing in pursuit of some A51 rep.  Who knows?

You signal your interest in an Area 51 proposal by committing to the proposal.

Finally, if you actually want an *answer* to your question, try it on an actual site.  Area 51 collects potential *questions*, but not *answers* to those questions.

Comment: Ok I'm a n00b and was not aware that there are not answers on Area 51. So with the same example I used in my post, if I did want to support the proposed site and also wanted an answer, I should post to both communities.(?) The A51 FAQ makes it sound like dupe questions are OK during advocacy.

Comment: Yes, you can post it as an example of what would be on-topic on the proposal on A51, and you can also post it on an actual SE site to get an answer.  (A51 doesn't really give you enough room to fully ask a question anyway; what you're posting there is basically the title.  So go ahead and turn it into a full question on another site.)  And we were all n00bs once -- no worries.